# How exactly do disease and damage points stack in Shadows of Esteren?

Tags: shadows-of-esteren

I'm having a bit of a struggle with understanding how disease and damage points stack. The way I'm currently seeing it is:

- Character has clear health track.
- Lets say the character acquires 2 disease points so I fill in the first two dots on the track.
- Later that day the character gets into a fight and ends up taking 4 damage points.

Now with all of that happening do I tick the four circles after the disease points? Then if the character acquires any more disease points do they fill in the tick marks or the next completely open circles?

Answer (score 1):

From **Book 1: Universe** (pg240), you should **fill** a health box for each disease point obtained, which stacks with damage points obtained (ticked). Disease points are harder to remove though, and if not taken care of, will quickly kill your character in a few days.

It actually gets worse, you cannot recover damage points if ill and wounded, meaning you are in a spiral to your death if you ignore it, some diseases can kill you after a couple of days unless you treat your wounds and rest, while weak diseases will, at most, cause an extra 5 points of damage that cannot be healed until the time has passed.

There are 4 types of diseases in the system, called **Virulance Levels**:

**Weak**: Difficult Threshold (**11**), Disease Points **5** (1/day)

**Mild**: Difficult Threshold (**14**), Disease Points **10** (2/day)

**Malignant**: Difficult Threshold (**17**), Disease Points **15** (3/day or death)

**Deadly**: Difficult Threshold (**20**), Disease Points **20** (4/day or death)

This defines the amount of Disease Points you get while ill and the difficult to heal it through spells

**Disease Points**

> The effects of a disease are simulated by Disease points, which worsen
>   the Character’s Health Condition. The Player fills the necessary
>   number of boxes in her Health Condition chart as the sickness wears
>   on. Damage points and Disease points stack, which can turn dangerous
>   for the PC. Diseases of Malignant and Deadly Virulence may inflict no
>   Disease points, resulting in instant death instead. Only a very
>   skilled physician (see below) or a mystical power (Demorthèn or from
>   the Temple) can then save the patient.

**Duration**

> In most cases, a disease lasts five days, during which the Character
>   suffers a certain amount of daily Disease points (1 point if the
>   disease is weak, 2 if it is mild, 3 if it is malignant and 4 if it is
>   deadly). In the case of diseases of Malignant or Deadly Virulence that
>   can kill, death occurs at the end of these five days. Some diseases
>   can evolve in a faster or slower way than the average; the Leader
>   divides the amount of Disease points by the number of days the illness
>   lasts (see the previous chart). For example, a Malignant disease
>   lasting only 3 days will inflict 5 daily Disease points.

**Diagnosis**

> Diagnosing an illness requires a Standard (11) Medicine roll. A
>   natural 1 on this roll means a wrong diagnosis, whereas a regular
>   failure simply means the Character cannot identify the disease. A
>   success gives the Virulence of the illness and ideas for adequate care
>   (see on the following page).

And finally

**Resting and Recovering**

> Resting can often allow a Character to recover from a disease, even a
>   dangerous one. She needs to rest as long as it is in effect, and she
>   will suffer the appropriate Disease points for its Virulence. However,
>   she will recover all of those points the day after the end of her
>   disease. If a Character does not rest, the disease may live on after
>   its normal five day duration; in that case, on the sixth day, the
>   patient has to make a Stamina roll related to the Virulence. A failure
>   means that the illness persists and deals the same number of daily
>   Disease points again (another Stamina roll must be made the following
>   day); a critical failure leads to death. A success means a remission
>   and a recovery from all the Disease points. When a Character is ill
>   and wounded, she cannot recover damage points due to injuries by
>   resting. Only medical care can allow it, but at the rate of one daily
>   Health point instead of the normal two.

Also, a character with the **Medicine Skill** can roll a Complicated check (14) to reduce the amount of Disease Points obtained by 1, but you must be resting all day. If the disease will kill a character instead of causing disease points, the Medicine check can save him with a (17) roll.